# Compute the power of a matrix in R

Tags: r

(1) I am looking for a package for computing the power of a matrix. If you have some good recommendation please let me know.

(2) I searched on the internet and followed what some said to install a package called "Malmig" in R but after selecting the mirror site, it failed:

> In install.packages("Malmig") : package ‘Malmig’ is not available

Some idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like the `Malmig` package is not available on official CRAN package releases, so you're better looking for a source version (that has to be compiled) or another mirror.

Comment: Malmig is on the CRAN archive: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Malmig/. You would need to compile it yourself in order to install it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Package expm provides the matrix %^% number operator notation for its function matpow():

```
> library(expm)    
> mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
> mat %^% 2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   66  102
[2,]   36   81  126
[3,]   42   96  150

# check
> mat %*% mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   66  102
[2,]   36   81  126
[3,]   42   96  150
```

There's also sqrtm() for taking roots and expm() for matrix exponential.

Answer (score 1):

There is the following code you can write:

> library(Biodem)
>   png(filename="images/mtx.exp_%03d.png" ,width=480, height=480)
>
> #### Name: mtx.exp
>
> #### Title: Calculates the n-th power of a matrix
>
> #### Aliases: mtx.exp
>
> #### Keywords: array manip methods
>
> #### ** Examples
>
> test<-matrix(c(1:16), 4,4)
>   pow.test<-mtx.exp(test,10)
>   pow.test

for more details:http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_man-2.9.0/library/Biodem/man/mtx.exp.html

Answer (score 1):

Or... you could use my own package, 'powerplus' (function 'Matpow'), that allows you to raise any diagonalizable matrix to any power (even complex). For non-diagonalizable matrices, you have the same capabilities as package expm (incidentally, I use it in Matpow's code). To the best of my knowledge, it currently is the most comprehensive R package that exists to deal with matrix exponentiation. Version 3.0 extends capabilities to (some) non-diagonalizable matrices too.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `matrixcalc` package, which also provides other matrix operations:

```
> require(matrixcalc)
> mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
> matrix.power(mat,2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   66  102
[2,]   36   81  126
[3,]   42   96  150
> mat%*%mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   66  102
[2,]   36   81  126
[3,]   42   96  150
```